Best way to work around with repetition of value thru groupby
It's quite hard to explain what I'm experiencing so it's best to just put it over here and explain.



EMPLOYEE_ID
EMPLOYEE_SUPERVISOR_ID
EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
EFFECTIVE_END_DATE




30665
61046
30/04/2021
30/09/2021


30665
8009098
30/09/2021
31/12/2021


30665
8009098
31/12/2021
31/07/2022


30665
73280
31/07/2022
31/08/2022


30665
73280
31/08/2022
30/09/2022


30665
73280
30/09/2022
30/09/2023


30665
73280
03/10/2023
31/10/2023


30665
73280
31/10/2023
01/12/2023


30665
79621
01/12/2023
04/12/2023


30665
79621
01/12/2023
04/12/2023


30665
73280
04/12/2023
15/01/2024


30665
73280
15/01/2024
15/03/2024


30665
73280
15/03/2024
14/05/2024


30665
73280
14/05/2024
15/05/2024


30665
73280
15/05/2024
17/05/2024



Here's the query I have in my attempt to get what I need:
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    SUPERVISOR_ID,
    MIN(EFFECTIVE_START) AS "EFFECTIVE_START",
    MAX(EFFECTIVE_END) AS "EFFECTIVE_END"
FROM
    EMP_TABLE
GROUP BY
    1, 2
ORDER BY
    EFFECTIVE_START ASC

Which resulted in this output; my problem here is the 73280 earn both the min and max:



EMPLOYEE_ID
SUPERVISOR_ID
EFFECTIVE_START
EFFECTIVE_END




30665
61046
30/04/2021
30/09/2021


30665
8009098
30/09/2021
31/07/2022


30665
73280
31/07/2022
01/12/2023


30665
73280
31/07/2022
17/05/2024


30665
79621
01/12/2023
04/12/2023



But my ideal result is this one:



EMPLOYEE_ID
SUPERVISOR_ID
EFFECTIVE_START
EFFECTIVE_END




30665
61046
30/04/2021
30/09/2021


30665
8009098
30/09/2021
31/07/2022


30665
73280
31/07/2022
01/12/2023


30665
79621
01/12/2023
04/12/2023


30665
73280
04/12/2023
17/05/2024




You need to break the grouping whenever there's a gap or change in the effective date ranges for the same supervisor :
WITH SupervisorGroups AS (
    SELECT
        EMPLOYEE_ID,
        EMPLOYEE_SUPERVISOR_ID,
        EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
        EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN LAG(EMPLOYEE_SUPERVISOR_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) = EMPLOYEE_SUPERVISOR_ID 
                     AND LAG(EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) = EFFECTIVE_START_DATE 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 
            END) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) AS GroupFlag
    FROM EMP_TABLE
)
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMPLOYEE_SUPERVISOR_ID AS SUPERVISOR_ID,
    MIN(EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) AS EFFECTIVE_START,
    MAX(EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) AS EFFECTIVE_END
FROM SupervisorGroups
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_SUPERVISOR_ID, GroupFlag
ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_START ASC;


I somehow get the idea of creating a flag to identify the supervisor here. Thanks for the idea. I somehow created a different column on the other hand as I'm getting this error: Window function [LAG(EMP_TABLE.EMPLOYEE_SUPERVISOR_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_TABLE.EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY EMP_TABLE.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE ASC NULLS LAST)] may not be nested inside another window function
